# ES6 - Import modules from project root directory (babel/node/npm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Before I continue, I have tried the following solutions:

- [Git: Babel plugin root import package](https://github.com/entwicklerstube/babel-plugin-root-import): Plugin doesn't seem to work alongside jest
- [SO: Configuring for babel jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098508/jest-and-es6-import-root-folder-based-imports-does-not-working)
- [SO: Create own babel plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068698/importing-node-modules-from-root-directory-using-es6-and-babel-node)
- Webpack aliasing is another solution however we don't use webpack

A project was handed over to me recently which utilizes relative import statements that can get pretty long and obscure (e.g. `import * as stuff from '../../../../../utilities/stuff'`). I'd like to simplify our import statements using the project's root directory in this fashion: `import * as stuff from '~/utilities/stuff`.

My understanding of the packages, dependencies and configurations is still in its infancy. It looks like we use babel for transpiling, however I don't see a core babel package - only `babel-jest` and `babel-polyfill`.

Here is our package.json:

```
{
    "name": "placeholder",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "animejs": "^2.2.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "classnames": "^2.2.5",
        "html-to-react": "^1.3.0",
        "htmlparser2-react": "0.0.4",
        "js-csp": "^1.0.1",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
        "react": "^16.0.0",
        "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
        "react-aria-menubutton": "^5.0.2",
        "react-dnd": "^2.5.1",
        "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.5.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
        "react-router": "^4.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
        "react-rte": "^0.11.0",
        "react-sidebar": "^2.3.2",
        "react-toasts": "^1.2.3",
        "react-transition-group": "^2.2.0",
        "react-virtualized": "^9.9.0",
        "redux": "^3.7.2",
        "redux-form": "^6.8.0",
        "sweetalert": "^2.0.8",
        "text-spinners": "^1.0.5",
        "uuid": "^3.1.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "^20.0.3",
        "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
        "jest-enzyme": "^3.8.2",
        "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
        "moment": "^2.18.1",
        "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
        "node-sass-chokidar": "0.0.3",
        "node-sass-magic-importer": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
        "react-docgen": "^2.18.0",
        "react-scripts": "1.0.13",
        "react-styleguidist": "^6.0.24",
        "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1",
        "redux-mock-store": "^1.3.0",
        "xhr-mock": "^1.9.1"
    }
}
```

And .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["react-app"],
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "retainLines": true
}
```

Our directory structure is as follows: `<rootDir>/src` where all js/jsx source files are contained within 'src'. This is the directory I'd like to configure to be the root (represented by a tilda (~)). Help would be greatly appreciated!