# Jest not able to import a module, but its working during npm run start

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nest

I have a standard nestjs project setup. I am trying to run e2e test written in `test/app.e2e-spec.ts` with `npm run test:e2e` command, but its throwing error

```
    Cannot find module 'src/utils/redisWrapper' from '../src/users/users.service.ts'

    Require stack:
      /Users/sanketh.bk/core/src/users/users.service.ts
      /Users/sanketh.bk/core/src/users/users.controller.ts
      /Users/sanketh.bk/core/src/users/users.module.ts
      /Users/sanketh.bkcore/src/app.module.ts
      app.e2e-spec.ts
```

Same error is not there while running `npm run start:dev` and it works as expected.

Some of the config files

`test/jest-e2e.json`

```
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  }
}
```

`jest` part of `package.json`

```
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

Some of the solutions i tried from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098508/jest-and-es6-import-root-folder-based-imports-does-not-working)

Adding

```
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>"
    ],
```

to `jest` object of `package.json`

It gives same error as before

2. Adding ```moduleNameMapper: {
   "src/(.*)": "/src/$1",
   },

```
to `test/jest-e2e.json`. It gives a different error:
```

```
Configuration error:

Could not locate module src/utils/redisWrapper mapped as:
/Users/sanketh.bk/core/test/src/$1.

Please check your configuration for these entries:
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/^src\/(.*)$/": "/Users/sanketh.bk/core/test/src/$1"
  },
  "resolver": undefined
}
```

````
3. Adding ```    "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "bower_components", "src"],
````

to `jest` object in `package.json` gives same error as initial error.

This is the `src/users/users.service.ts` file. One thing i noticed is if i change absolute import
`import { redisWrapper } from 'src/utils/redisWrapper';`

to relative import

`import { redisWrapper } from '../utils/redisWrapper';`

the error goes away and points to next absolute import instead of this

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Users } from '../common/entities/users.entity/entities/Users';
import { redisWrapper } from 'src/utils/redisWrapper';
import { UserInteractionEvents } from './entities/UserInteractionEvents';

const redis = new redisWrapper();
```